# Lorentz Generator help

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, lie-algebra

I am having trouble understanding the following results from David Tong's lectures on QFT. Could anybody explain how the deltas are used? I just started reviewing basic tensors and I find the deltas really confusing. How does he get to those matrices?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First things first - do you understand how to get 4.9 from 4.8?

Comment: Hi Jacob, no this is what I am asking. How do you get to the matrices using 4.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, $(\mathcal{M}^{01})^\mu{}_\nu=\eta^{0\mu}\delta^1{}_\nu-\eta^{1\mu}\delta^0{}_\nu$. There are exactly two nonzero entries, viz.$$(\mathcal{M}^{01})^0{}_1=(\mathcal{M}^{01})^1{}_0=1$$in the $+---$ convention (i.e. $\eta^{00}=-\eta^{11}=1$). Thus $\mathcal{M}^{01}$ is as shown in Eq. (4.9). You can similarly check $\mathcal{M}^{12}$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

These are Kronecker deltas, $\delta^\mu_\nu=1$ if $\mu=\nu$ and zero otherwise. Let us look at  $\mathcal M^{01}$. This is a $4\times 4$ matrix with elements
$$(\mathcal M^{01})^\mu_{\;\nu} = \eta^{0\mu} \delta^1_\nu - \eta^{1\mu}\delta^0_\nu$$
Now $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric $\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$. So The only non-zero elements of $\mathcal M^{01}$ are $(\mathcal M^{01})^0_{\;1}$ and $(\mathcal M^{01})^1_{\;0}$. Similarly for $\mathcal M^{12}$.